# Mouse input for lwjgl

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am new to LWJGL3 and this has probably been answered elsewhere, however I have not been able to find it so I would appreciate some help, in my code for finding out everything about the mouse that I can later use for movement

I get a couple of errors Return type in method is missing etc, even tho it works further down the line, when I move it below more code, but then the top code still fails, the code:

```
package input.mouse;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWCursorPosCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWScrollCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallback;

public class minputs {

glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseCallback = new GLFWMouseButtonCallback() {

    public void invoke(long window, int button, int action, int mods) {

    }
});

glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseCallback = GLFWMouseButtonCallback.create((window, button, action, mods) -> {

}));


glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, posCallback = new GLFWCursorPosCallback() {
    public void invoke(long window, double xpos, double ypos) {

    }
});

glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scrollCallback = new GLFWScrollCallback() {

    public void invoke(long window, double xoffset, double yoffset) {

    }
});

glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scrollCallback = GLFWScrollCallback.create((window, xoffset, yoffset) - 
> {

}));



}
```

is void for

```
glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseCallback = new GLFWMouseButtonCallback() {

public void invoke(long window, int button, int action, int mods) {

}
});

glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseCallback = 
GLFWMouseButtonCallback.create((window, button, action, mods) -> {

}));
```

Comment: Have you initialized the callback first, ie. `private static GLFWCursorPosCallback posCallback`.